# Generate rows with time intervals between 2 dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have table in which Sunday to Saturdy "Doctor Start" and "End Time" is given.
I want to create time slots of 15 minutes.

On the basis of that, the patient clicks on calendar datetime interval which shows slots that have already been booked.

[image]

Comment: Good luck with that. Unless! you have a real question.

Comment: what u dont understand in this

Comment: I understand, what you have written,  however I don't see any question/details. Have a look at  - [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @SudiptaMondal now image is attached.u can now understand real question

Comment: @arman - [please post text rather than images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 5):

The following example shows how to split time into slices of 15 minutes. It uses hierarchical query. A little bit of explanation:

- line 2: `trunc` function, applied to a date value, returns "beginning" of that day (at midnight). Adding `15 / (24*60)` adds 15 minutes (as there are 24 hours in a day and 60 minutes in an hour). Multiplying 15 by `level` works as a "loop", i.e. adds 15-by-15-by-15 ... minutes to previous value.
- line 4: similar to line 2, but it makes sure that a day (24 hours * 60 minutes) is divided to 15-minutes parts
- line 6: start time is trivial
- line 7: end time just adds 15 minutes to `start_time`
- line 9: return only time between 10 and 16 hours (you don't have patients at 02:15 AM, right?)

---

```
SQL> with fifteen as
  2    (select trunc(sysdate) + (level * 15)/(24*60) c_time
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= (24*60) / 15
  5    )
  6  select to_char(c_time, 'hh24:mi') start_time,
  7         to_char(c_time + 15 / (24 * 60), 'hh24:mi') end_time
  8  from fifteen
  9  where extract(hour from cast (c_time as timestamp)) between 10 and 15;

START_TIME END_TIME
---------- ----------
10:00      10:15
10:15      10:30
10:30      10:45
10:45      11:00
11:00      11:15
11:15      11:30
11:30      11:45
11:45      12:00
12:00      12:15
12:15      12:30
12:30      12:45
12:45      13:00
13:00      13:15
13:15      13:30
13:30      13:45
13:45      14:00
14:00      14:15
14:15      14:30
14:30      14:45
14:45      15:00
15:00      15:15
15:15      15:30
15:30      15:45
15:45      16:00

24 rows selected.

SQL>
```